# Ошибка среза по времени

Tags: python, pandas

Помогите, пожалуйста, с выборкой по дате. Почему-то получается пустой датафрейм, хотя данные есть. Как сделать срез по двум заданными датам?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если с 2018 по 2019, то можно так

1. Если date это индекс

   df.loc['2018-01-01':'2019-12-31']
2. Если не является индексом

   df[(df['date'] >= '2018-01-01') & (df['date'] <= '2019-12-31')]